# 3.6.10 Tao Analysis, need help wth checking my proof and seeking any advice for the proof-writing itself.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Proposition 3.6.1.4: Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then $X \cup Y$ is finite and $\#(X \cup Y ) \le \#(X) + \#(Y)$

Lemma 1:  Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For any $n$ finite sets $A_1,...,A_n$ with $\#A_i < 2$ for any $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)\le n$,

We use induction on $n$. If $n=0$, then the statement is vacuously true since the union of nothing is undefined. Suppose inductively, we have shown that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that for any $n$ finite sets $A_1,...,A_n$ with $\#A_i < 2$ for any $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)\le n$, We will now show that for for any $n+1$ sets $A_1,...,A_{n+1}$ with $\#A_i < 2$ for any $i \in \{1,...,n+1\}$, $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n+1\}} A_i)\le n$. Let there be $n+1$ sets $A_1,...,A_{n+1}$ with $\#A_i < 2$ for any $i \in \{1,...,n+1\}$, then by our inductive hypothesis $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)\le n$. Then, by proposition 3.6.14, $\#((\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i) \cup A_{n+1})\le \#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)+\#(A_{n+1})<n+2$. Equivalently, this also means that  $\#((\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i) \cup A_{n+1})\le n+1$ as desired. This closes the induction.

Exercise 3.6.10: Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be finite sets such that $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)>n$, then there exists $i \in \{1,..., n\}$ such that $\#(Ai) \ge 2$

We use contraposition. If there does not exist $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ st $\#(A_i)\ge 2$, then this will mean that for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $\#(A_i) < 2$ . Then by lemma 1, this will mean that $\#(\bigcup_{i\in\{1,...,n\}} A_i)\le n$. $\square$

Could anyone help me check if i am using contraposition correctly? Also, is there any cleaner way to organise or write the proof for Lemma 1, been feeling that my proof-writing is needlessly long and messy but im not sure where to clean-up stuff.

Comment: I did not grind through your proof. It might be easier to show that if $X,Y$ are disjoint then $|X \cup Y| = |X|+|Y|$. You can create an explicit bijection. Then write $X \cup Y = (X\setminus Y) \cup (X \cap Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)$ and note that $|X| = |X\setminus Y| +|X \cap Y| $, etc.

Comment: [[A]] Try not staying with "vacuously" true $n=0$ , you should at least Prove it for $n=1$ & for $n=2$ & maybe for $n=3$ , then move to Induction for Lemma. [[B]] Proof is Correct for Exercise. [[C]] My Outline for Lemma : When new Set is Empty , then Count will not Increase. If new Set has 1 element which is already encountered , then Count will not Increase. If new Set has 1 element which is new , then Count will Increase by 1. DONE. [[D]] We might even try that without Induction !

Comment: The proof looks correct to me. For the lemma you can use contrapposizione and the pidgeonhole principle. If the Number of element Is bigger than $n$ by the pidgeonhole principle at least one of the set has more than one element in it (maybe he wants you to prove the pidgeonhole principle?)